# Flutter gives null error, but works after restart

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder, flutter-futurebuilder

I am new to Flutter, I am trying to fetch data from firestore collection. I am using FutureBuilder with Provider, but it shows null error on initial & runs perfectly after restarting the app.

Here is the code to fetch the data:

```
                FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection(collec.collectionProducts)
                        .get(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return Consumer<CartItemCounter>(
                      builder: (BuildContext context, CartItemCounter cart, _) {
                        if (cart.checkProductAddedToCart(model.productId)) {
                          return Row(....);
```

Error
[image: error-image]

code for futurebuilder
[image: widget code]

code for ui
[image: ui widget code]
(here i have changed the collection name)

How can i solve it. I have tried every solution available on online. Thank you

Comment: is a circularprogressindicator showing on the screen?

Comment: yes for a while

Comment: make sure the collection and the where condition is correct, what does `snap.data.documents.length` give you?

Comment: it is giving null. since the collection and condition is okay

Comment: if it is giving null, then you are not getting anything, what does `print(itemHolder)` give you?

Comment: it displays the chosen category from previous screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226340/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-arvina-kori).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where is the error coming from?**

According to this, the issue is coming from your `Consumer<CartItemCounter>`.

**What does the error mean?**

This error, `The method 'x' was called on null.`, means that the class where this `x` function is written, that class is null.

**What is the reason for this error in my code?**

Your `Consumer<CartItemCounter>` provides an instance of `CartItemCounter` by the name `cart`. Then, you call function `checkProductAddedToCart`.

The error message is telling you that `cart` is null which is being given to you by the `Consumer` widget. This means that Consumer probably also did not find that Provider. I expect that there should be an error log by `Provider`, telling you that CartItemCounter was not found.

**Possible Solution**

Try '*providing*' CartItemCounter.

How do you do that? Go to the top of your app's widget tree to `MaterialApp`, wrap it inside a `MultiProvider` or `ChangeNotifierProvider` and then pass your new CartItemCounter as `value`.

Read [Official Provider Docs](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#usage) for more info on how to expose a provider.

***You need to upload your complete log, so that I can further help you.***

Comment: ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (c) => CartItemCounter()), Yes i have already added Provider in main.dart

Comment: Yes it worked. I was using, ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (c) => CartItemCounter()). When i added, ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: CartItemCounter()), i started to get null error on length. In the end i added both. now it's working. Silly me this thing took 1 whole day. Thank you mate..

Comment: Hey, it worked fine, but i didn't noticed one thing that when i restart the app, all the data stored in Map object gets deleted. How can i avoid it? or how can i store it?

Comment: You will have to save the cart items to the device's local storage and reload from there when application starts.

The most easiest & fastest way to do this is Hive plugin. Study that.

Answer (score 0):

Always check the result for the future builder, ie snapshot has data.

Place a switch condition or if-else bock depending on the status of the snapshot.

check the example from the official doc [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Yes it has. Because the circular progress is not showing. And also it starts working after restarting the app.

Comment: I checked with switch block, there is data available but still same error coming

Comment: try wrapping your `cart` with an if condition to check if its null, before accessing the method `checkProductAddedToCart`